# Find all latest data for all unique id in sequalizer?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a table with temperature with `roomid`, `temp` and `addedon` 
there are multiple data for same roomid, i can get latest data for one roomid using squalizer as

```
var opts = {
           where: {
           roomid: {  $in:[1]
            } 
          },
        order: [ ['addedon', 'DESC'] ]
        ,limit: 1
        }    
return models['psql']['roomtemp'].findAll(opts).nodeify(cb);
```

it return latest data for only one row having `roomid` 1 how can i get result of all `roomid` latest temperature ?

Reference: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/#attribuest

Answer (score 0):

You can select `DISTINCT` rows on the `roomid` column. See [enter link description here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2996)

```
var opts = {
    attributes: [sequelize.fn('DISTINCT', sequelize.col('roomid'))]
    order: [ ['addedon', 'DESC'] ]

}    
return models['psql']['roomtemp'].findAll(opts).nodeify(cb);
```

Comment: removing limit :1 give result off all data for same id

Comment: I misunderstood your question. I have updated my answer to use the 'DISTINCT' function instead.